# Another problem with code; boolean?

Tags: arduino-uno

Maybe another problem for trained eyes. I seem to get the alarm to cycle regardless of the state of "trigsensor" and "away" (they should both need to be true in order for the alarm to run after an incorrect code is entered). Thanks for any response to this, as I am still learning C:

```
//////////////////////////// initialize & includes //////////////////////////
#include <elapsedMillis.h>
#include "SIM900.h"
#include "sms.h"
#include "Keypad.h"
#include <GSM.h>
SMSGSM sms;

int PIR_SensorPin = 2;
int Alarm_OutPin = 11; //green
int Light_OutPin = 12; //red
int alarm_count = 0;
volatile boolean trigsensor = false;
boolean away = false;
const byte interruptPin = 2;
int z = 0;
int i = 0;

//////////////////////////// setup keyPad //////////////////////////
const byte ROWS = 4; //four rows
const byte COLS = 4; //four columns
char keys[ROWS][COLS] =
{
  {
    '1', '2', '3', 'A'
  }
  ,
  {
    '4', '5', '6', 'B'
  }
  ,
  {
    '7', '8', '9', 'C'
  }
  ,
  {
    '*', '0', '#', 'D'
  }
};
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {
  6, 7, A2, A3 // row pin# on keypad to Arduino pin#, ie Row Pin #1 goes to Arduino Pin #6, etc.
}; // connect to the row pinouts of the keypad
byte colPins[COLS] = {
  3, A0, A1, A4
}; // connect to the column pinouts of the keypad
Keypad keypad = Keypad(makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );
const char PIN[5] = {
  '9', '6', '7', '9', '#'
}; // PIN number
char key_input[5] = {
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0
}; // used for comparison

//////////////////////////////// setup ///////////////////////////////////
void setup() {
  Serial.begin (9600);  // Establish Serial connection;
  pinMode (Alarm_OutPin, OUTPUT);   // Set pinMode.
  pinMode (Light_OutPin, OUTPUT);   // Set pinMode.
  pinMode (PIR_SensorPin, INPUT);   // Set pinMode.
  digitalWrite (Alarm_OutPin, LOW); // Set output pins to LOW for start.
  digitalWrite (Light_OutPin, LOW); // Set output pins to LOW for start.
  digitalWrite (PIR_SensorPin, LOW);
  Serial.println ("GSM Alarm starting up."); // Serial message that GSM shield is starting up
  if (gsm.begin(4800)) {    // Set GSM shield to recommended 4800 baud rate.
    Serial.println ("Status = Network READY");
    digitalWrite (Alarm_OutPin, HIGH);
  }
  delay (10000);
  attachInterrupt (digitalPinToInterrupt (2), trigger, HIGH); // PIR as interrupt
  Serial.println ("System Ready");
}

//////////////////////////////// void loop ///////////////////////////////////
void loop() {
  if (trigsensor == true) {
    alarm();
  }
  else {
    readKeypad();
  }
}

//////////////////////////////// void trigger ///////////////////////////////////
void trigger() {
  trigsensor = true;
  //  alarm();
}

//////////////////////////////// void alarm ///////////////////////////////////
void alarm() {
  Serial.print ("away="); Serial.print (away); Serial.print (" ");Serial.print ("trigsensor=");Serial.println (trigsensor);
  Serial.println("at Alarm");
  if (away == true && trigsensor == true) { ////////////////////////////////
    // (sms.SendSMS("**********", "***Motion Detected in Studio!***"));
    Serial.println ("MOTION detected: SMS Sent");
  }
  // else if (trigsensor == true) {  /////////////////////////////////////////////
  for (alarm_count = 0; alarm_count <= 5; alarm_count++) { // Cycle outputs if triggered
    digitalWrite (Light_OutPin, HIGH); delay (1000); // On/Off/On/Off/Off
    digitalWrite (Light_OutPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite (Alarm_OutPin, HIGH); delay (1000);
    digitalWrite (Alarm_OutPin, LOW); // End by turning off light
    Serial.println(alarm_count);
  }
  digitalWrite (Alarm_OutPin, HIGH);
  trigsensor = false;
  away = false;
  readKeypad();
}

//////////////////////////////// read Keypad ///////////////////////////////////
void readKeypad() {  //attachInterrupt (digitalPinToInterrupt (2), trigger, HIGH); // reattach interrupt
  char key = keypad.getKey();
  if (key != NO_KEY) { // if a keypad input
    key_input[z] = key;
    tone(10, 900, 100);
    Serial.print("Key_input["); Serial.print(z); Serial.print("] = "); Serial.println(key);
    z++;
    if (z >= sizeof(key_input)) {
      z = 0;
    }
    switch (key) {
      case '*': // resets key_inputs to "0"
        z = 0;
        break;
      case '#': // pressed to "enter"
        z = 0;
        for ( i = 0;   i < 4 ;  i++ ) {
          Serial.print(key_input[i]);
        }
        Serial.println ("-------");
        delay(100); // for extra de-bounce
        checkPIN();
        break;
    }
  }
}

//////////////////////////////// check PIN ///////////////////////////////////
void checkPIN() {
  Serial.println ("@ checkPIN ");
  int correct = 0;
  int i;
  for ( i = 0;   i < (sizeof(PIN) - 1) ;  i++ ) {
    if (key_input[i] == PIN[i]) {
      correct++;
    }
  }
  if (correct >= sizeof(PIN) - 1) {
    Serial.print ("# correct = "); Serial.println (correct); Serial.println (sizeof(PIN) - 1);
    correctPIN();
  }
  else {
    incorrectPIN();
  }
}

//////////////////////////////// correct PIN ///////////////////////////////////
void correctPIN() {              // do this if correct PIN entered
  Serial.println ("@ correct PIN ");
  digitalWrite (Alarm_OutPin, HIGH);
  digitalWrite (Alarm_OutPin, LOW);
  detachInterrupt(0);
  trigsensor = false;
}

//////////////////////////////// incorrect PIN /////////////////////////////////
void incorrectPIN() {           // do this if incorrect PIN entered
  Serial.println ("@ incorrect PIN ");
  delay(10000); // a slight delay aded to allow leaving without triggering the alarm
  trigsensor = false;
  away = true; /////////////////////////////////
  digitalWrite (Alarm_OutPin, HIGH);
  attachInterrupt (digitalPinToInterrupt (2), trigger, HIGH);
  alarm();
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this: `if (trigsensor == true)` be more along the lines of `if (trigsensor == true && away == true)` in the `loop()` function?

Comment: Would that really matter, as the problem seems to be the output of the operand, regardless of where it might be placed? I just tried it in the loop function and not any different.

Comment: `attachInterrupt()` doesn't support attaching on `HIGH`. Oh, and instead of `if (trigsensor == true)` you could write `if ((trigsensor == true) == true)`, or maybe `if (((trigsensor == true) == true) == true)` (just kidding, `if (trigsensor)` is all you need).

Comment: Using "HIGH" with attacheInterrupt on a UNO seems to work. Is it a reliability concern?